# Abelian category induced by commutative ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

If $R$ is any ring, then ${}_R \mathsf{Mod}$ is an abelian category. We cannot detect commutativity of $R$ from ${}_R \mathsf{Mod}$, since for example $R$ and the matrix ring $M_n(R)$ are always Morita-equivalent, i.e. have equivalent module categories. However, if $R$ is (Morita-equivalent to) a commutative ring, then I suspect that ${}_R \mathsf{Mod}$ satisfies some properties which are not shared by arbitrary module categories of rings. Therefore, my question is:

Let $\mathcal{L}_{\mathsf{AbCat}}$ be the language of abelian categories: objects, morphisms, source, target, compositions and sums of morphisms, direct sums, kernels, cokernels. What is an example of a formula in $\mathcal{L}_{\mathsf{AbCat}}$, which is satisfied in ${}_R \mathsf{Mod}$ for commutative rings $R$, but which is not safisfied in all ${}_S \mathsf{Mod}$ for rings $S$? Of course, we may also use derived concepts, such as Ext groups.

If we add colimits to our language, then we may define compact objects and the condition is precisely that there is a compact projective generator $P$ such that $\mathrm{End}(P)$ is commutative. But this is merely a reformulation of the condition being equivalent to ${}_R \mathsf{Mod}$ for some commutative ring $R$. I am looking for more intrinsic properties. Also, I am not only looking for characterizations of module categories induced by commutative rings. Some necessary properties would also be nice.

Comment: Without adding colimits to the language, one necessary property is that there is a projective generator with commutative endomorphism ring. That feels like cheating, but it leads to what seems an interesting question (I've thought about it a bit without managing to answer it): if there is a projective generator with commutative endomorphism ring, must there be a finitely generated projective generator with commutative endomorphism ring?